# How to assign a variable for each item of the loop

Tags: javascript

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataForecast.list.length; i += 8) {
  const data = dataForecast.list[i].dt_txt;
}
```

This loops gives out 5 intended looped pieces of data but I'm struggling to assign each loop to its own variable.

Comment: So, you intend to have 5 variables at the end of the loop, why?

Comment: Maybe worth looking at [Scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope). But as @Undo has stated in the answer below, an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Array) would work well for what you are possibly trying to do.

Comment: Currently each loop is actually having its own variable, only that the variable is local to the loop, you can't access it outside of the loop. You can't create variable names dynamically in JS, you've to learn to use data structures like array instead.

Comment: There is a helper method available for pulling out data from an array of objects: [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map): `const data = dataForecast.list.map(list => list.dt_txt);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an array

```js
const dataArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < dataForecast.list.length; i += 8) {
  const data = dataForecast.list[i].dt_txt;
  dataArr.push(data);
}
console.log(dataArr); // access the array
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to dynamically generate and assign variable value. For this you can use **eval()** method like below:

```
dataArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var x = 'data'

for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
  eval('var ' + x + i + '= ' + dataArray[i] + ';');
}
console.log("data0=" + data0);
console.log("data1=" + data1);
console.log("data2=" + data2);
console.log("data3=" + data3);
console.log("data4=" + data4);
```

***Note:** It's not recommended to use **eval()** method due to security reasons. You can read more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval*